# SQL Query to only pull one record for first day of month, for every month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that has one record per day. E.g. (this is just the date col of the table)

```
2018-07-08 03:00:00
2018-07-07 03:00:00
2018-07-06 03:00:00
2018-07-05 03:00:00
2018-07-04 03:00:00
2018-07-03 03:00:00
2018-07-02 03:00:00
2018-07-01 03:00:00
2018-06-30 03:00:00
2018-06-29 03:00:00
```

This data goes back a few years

I want to pull just the first day of month record, for all months in the table.

What is the SQL to do that?

(On SQL Server 2014)

Comment: DATEPART(day, data) = 1

Comment: In contrast to some of the answers here I prefer to use a Calendar table and construct the start/end ranges, but at one row a day that's not going to be a large performance advantage, if any (and will be a large maintenance penalty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your time are zeroed all you do need is to get everything where [**DATEPART**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is first day.

```
select * from dbo.MyTable mt where DATEPART(day, mt.MyDate) = 1
```

It will work if you got one row per day. Off course you will need to use DISTINCT or an aggregation if you got more than one row per day.

Answer (score 3):

I would use the `day()` function:

```
select t.*
from t
where day(t.MyDate) = 1;
```

Neither this nor `datepart()` are ANSI/ISO-standard, but there are other databases that support `day()`.  The standard function is `extract(day from t.MyDate)`.

If you want the first record in the table for each month -- but for some months, that might not be day 1 -- then you can use `row_number()`.  One method is:

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by year(mydate), month(mydate) order by day(mydate) asc);
```

Comment: ...why not just `ORDER BY myDate`?  Which would also cover the case where there are multiple rows for a given day.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse  . . . Because this returns the first recent day in each month.

Comment: Obviously it does, as would ordering by the base date itself, since it's already partitioned.    I was just wondering if there was a reason to choose one over the other?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` function :

```
select *
from (select *, row_number() over (partition by datepart(year, date), datepart(month, date) order by datepart(day, date)) seq
      from table
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

Perhaps you also need `year` in `partition` clause.

Comment: Note that this gets the first-day-of-month _present_, which isn't necessarily the actual first day of the month.  Also, it will condense all years, and give you a non-deterministic row for each month.

Answer (score 0):

Though this has been answered, you can use date from parts in MS SQL as well.

```
  create table  #temp (dates date) 

 insert into #temp values  ('2018-01-02'),('2018-01-05'), ('2018-01-09'), ('2018-01-10')

 select * from #temp 

 dates
 2018-01-02
 2018-01-05
 2018-01-09
 2018-01-10

 You can use this to get beginning of the month 

     select DATEFROMPARTS(year(dates), month(dates), 01) Beginningofmonth  from #temp 
     group by DATEFROMPARTS(year(dates), month(dates), 01)

 Output: 
 Beginningofmonth
 2018-01-01
```